# Reading MVC4 WebApi Multipart Data

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm sending multipart form-data to my WebApi controller. The content I'm interested in  includes both an image and another non-image value. I can read the image no problem, but can't figure out how to read the **username** part (with **andy** as the value). It's not in the FormData property on the provider. How can I get it?

**Multi-part Form Data**

```
------------ei4KM7KM7ae0GI3Ef1gL6ei4ae0ae0
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Filename"

image.jpg
------------ei4KM7KM7ae0GI3Ef1gL6ei4ae0ae0
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="username"

andy
------------ei4KM7KM7ae0GI3Ef1gL6ei4ae0ae0
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Filedata"; filename="image.jpg"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream


------------ei4KM7KM7ae0GI3Ef1gL6ei4ae0ae0
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Upload"

Submit Query
------------ei4KM7KM7ae0GI3Ef1gL6ei4ae0ae0--
```

**Controller Code**

```
string root = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");
MultipartFormDataStreamProvider provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);

var task = request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider).ContinueWith<HttpResponseMessage>(o =>
{ 
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 7):

There is a good article on this [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/sending-html-form-data,-part-2)

Your `provider` variable should have a NameValueCollection property called FormData. You should therefore be able to do something like:

```
string username = provider.FormData.GetValues("username").SingleOrDefault();
```

NB. I had to update my References to see the FormData property. My version of RC was:
Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client.4.0.20505.0 using Nuget to update all WebApi and MVC 4 references gave me Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client.4.0.20710.0.

Comment: What does "NB" stand for?

Comment: Okay; FWIW, I'm not a bean, either.

Comment: Maybe it means Not Bad?

Answer (score 1):

So I found what I think is probably a hacky way to do this:

```
string username = provider.Contents.First(x=>x.Headers.ContentDisposition.Name == "\"username\"").ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

Is there a more-preferred way?